# Questions for a homepage

Tags: html, css

I am making a clean landing page for my team but I am unsure on how I would do the following: Make the content is the red box appear first then have other content below it so users can simply just scroll down to view it. I would like the content in the red box to take the full size of the screen as well.

Im looking for something like: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-landing-page/

Any help guys?

[image: An example of what I am looking to make]

My Code:

```
<body>

        <input type="checkbox" id="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-checkbox">

    <nav class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="logo-nav"> < /> </a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <label for="navbar-checkbox" class="navbar-handle"></label>
    </nav>

    <div class="content-main">
        <h1>System</h1>
        <p>"A new look into technology"</p>
    </div>

    <div class="otherContent">
        <img src="img/PHP.jpg">
        <h1>Testing</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

CSS: 

      /*Main CSS*/

.content-main{
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}

.otherContent{
  width:100vw;
  height:1000px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:aqua;

  }
```

Comment: from what I know you will need javascript (easyer with jQuery) to set the window or view-port heights ..

Comment: Could you please crate a example of how i would do this please?

Comment: viewport height and width we can set using css , no need to have JavaScript.Have a look at the below answer

Comment: You can't just upload all your code and expect us to go through all of it to see where the problem is, so please keep it minimal. Follow [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) for more info on creating minimalistic questions

Comment: @Jayababu you are right, if you don't care about browser support:  http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hope this will help you.

```css
.landingContent{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background:green
  }
.otherContent{
  width:100vw;
  height:1000px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:aqua;
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="landingContent"></div>
<div class="otherContent"></div>
```

Comment: Ive tried you code and it has not helped me. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried so that I can help you

Comment: Thank you, I have re written some of my code and it now works :D